# useState not updating the state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rendering, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to filter users with input search inside the function `searchByName`.
I manage to get the right result in `copyUsers`variable but unfortunately it does not reflect the change inside the state.

Forgot to mention, using bare React-App with hooks and typescript.

For example, i write 'p' in the input and recieve the right filtered array in `copyUsers` variable but then i push it into the state it does not update.

Attaching screenshot for understanding the situation better:

[image]

what i have tried instead setFilteredUsers(copyUsers):

- setFilteredUsers(() => [...filteredUsers, copyUsers]);
- setFilteredUsers(() => copyUsers);

main component:

```
  const { value } = useSelector(({ test }: any) => test);

  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Users>([]);

  const [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = useState<Users>([]);

  const [searchNameValue, setSearchNameValue] = useState<string>("");

  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState<User>();

  const [searchOrderBy, setSearchOrderBy] = useState<string>("");

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const get = async () => {
      const response = await ApiTest.testGet();
      setUsers(response);
      setSearchOrderBy("desc");
    };
    get();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchByName();
    setNewOrder();
  }, [searchOrderBy]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('search value changed!', searchNameValue);
      searchByName();
      setNewOrder()
  }, [searchNameValue]);

  const setNewOrder = () => {
    if (users.length) {
      let copyUsers = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(filteredUsers.length ? filteredUsers : users)
      );
      switch (searchOrderBy) {
        case "desc":
          copyUsers.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if (a.id > b.id) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (b.id > a.id) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          });
          break;

        case "asc":
          copyUsers.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
            if (b.id > a.id) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.id > b.id) {
              return 1;
            }
            return 0;
          });
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }
      filteredUsers.length ? setFilteredUsers(copyUsers) : setUsers(copyUsers);
    }
  };

  const searchByName = () => {
    if (searchNameValue) {
      let copyUsers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users));
      copyUsers = copyUsers.filter((user: User) => {
        return user.name
          .toLocaleLowerCase()
          .includes(searchNameValue.toLocaleLowerCase());
      });
      console.log("copyUsers =", copyUsers);
      setFilteredUsers(copyUsers);
      console.log("filteredUsers =", filteredUsers);
    }
  };

  const UserCards =
    !!users.length &&
    (searchNameValue ? filteredUsers : users).map(user => {
      return (
        <UserCard
          selectedUser={selectedUser}
          setSelectedUser={(user: User) => setSelectedUser(user)}
          user={user}
        />
      );
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <FilterBar
        searchOrderBy={searchOrderBy}
        searchSetOrderBy={(value: string) => setSearchOrderBy(value)}
        setSearchNameValue={(value: string) => setSearchNameValue(value)}
        searchNameValue={searchNameValue}
      />
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexFlow: "wrap" }}>{UserCards}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: As a general rule please provide sandbox solution instead of wall of text.
there are 2 ways to update state:
1.setState(newState)
2.setState(prevState =>  [...prevstate, ...newState] );

Also setState is async so there's a chance that's causing a problem

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering because you lead me to the answer, it ain't pretty because in useState method (as far i know) there is no callback after setting new value like in class component -> ```setState(newState, ()=>{//callback})``` so i used setTimeout with 0ms to force it to be async.

If you know any other way i can use useState as async please let me know.

Comment: `setState` is an async call, you won't get `filteredUser` immediately after `setFilteredUsers` due to this.

Comment: Yeah i already understand it, watch my previous comment.
So i still dont know how do you make useState sync ? i know how to do it with callback in class component but it is not possible with hooks

As i said in my last comment, my only solution was to add setTimeOut with 0ms to force the useState to be sync

Comment: Simple example done at work so forgive for bizzare names etc.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-tzbkh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

There's no need to abuse hooks when you don't need to

Comment: I do appreciate it Ernestas but this does not provide any solution for making the useState sync but you really simplify the function (deleted the deepcopy).

For example i did:

```const searchByName = () => {
    if (searchNameValue) {
        setFilteredUsers(
          users.filter(user => {
            if (user) {
              return user.name
                .toLocaleLowerCase()
                .includes(searchNameValue.toLocaleLowerCase());
            }
          })
        );
    }
  };
```

And yet it does not work without setTimeOut with 0ms